# Centering CSS 4x4

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html/css and I need help centering my images in the middle and to stack 4x4 in a way it looks like this:

[image]

Currently, I have it like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```css
.welcome {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

div.gallery {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  color: #bb07ac;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: .5s
}

a {
  transition: .5s
}

html {
  background: #faf8da
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/css.css">

<div class="welcome">
  <br>
  <p style="font-size:1.5em;" class="font-light font-white">welcome</p>

</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be the flexbox way and I cleaned up a few things. With flexbox, just set the gallery items to wrap and be 25% width and you'll get 4 per row.

I also changed gallery to have `box-sizing: border-box` so that when you hover you won't have the last item of the row wrap.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .gallery {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* not relevent to SO question below */

.welcome {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  /* position: center; not valid */
  object-fit: cover;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  color: #bb07ac;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: .5s
}

a {
  transition: .5s
}

html {
  background: #faf8da
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<div class="welcome">
  <br>
  <p style="font-size:1.5em;" class="font-light font-white">welcome</p>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
      <img src="pic/1.png" alt="Cinque Terre" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
      <img src="pic/2.png" alt="Cinque Terre" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
      <img src="pic/3.png" alt="Cinque Terre" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="pic/4.png" alt="Cinque Terre" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="pic/5.png" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="pic/6.png" alt="Cinque Terre" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="pic/7.png" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="pic/8.png" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400" class="center">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Idk if i'm dumb or not but how would you implement it into the current code I have right now? https://codepen.io/freedom1060/pen/mdVaxvO

Comment: Well, you have floats in there so if you want to use flex-box you'd take out all your float stuff and instead do like what is in my post. Your row would be the container and the columns are the gallery items. 

With that said - you're nearly there with the floats as it is, the padding on the columns is causing the wrapping you're seeing. Try just adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your column class - then padding will be included as part of the width.

Comment: I placed box-sizing: border-box; under .column and tried resizing the padding and its still doesn't work. I see your code snippet and that's how I want it to look. Is it cool if you can help edit the codepen by any chance to make it look like that?

Comment: You don't need to resize padding, you can set the padding to whatever you want. Adding box-sizing: border-box and making the width 33.33% gives you 3 columns and that's exactly what your codepen shows now - so what's the problem? If you want 4 columns, just make the width 25%...

Comment: Okay so the code you sent is here = https://codepen.io/freedom1060/pen/MWyyMzj
This is what I have right now = https://codepen.io/freedom1060/pen/mdVaxvO

You see how yours is nice and big and it events out between the rows? I want that but I don't know how to edit the code to make it like that.

Comment: @Freedom sorry but that's a bit beyond SO scope - I answered the question at hand (as well as the other poster). Both answers work so you should mark one as correct. If you have another specific question about another issue you're struggling with, you should ask another question. You're so close though and I gave you a working example that you like. I'd suggest you start with that so you have the layout, and integrate your content into it.